# How to listen to value changes of a separate Flow screen component inside an LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have a screen flow with a custom LWC component and a Date field like so:

[image]

The AG Grid Datatable v2 is my custom component and the Quote Expiry Date is the Date component.

What I want to do is, every time the user changes the Quote Expiry Date, I want to be notified in my LWC AG Grid Datatable v2 component. Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

If the components are not in the same Lightning App then you want the LMS - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation

If you are able to relate the two lwcs via a parent/child relationship then you are looking for lwc events - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/events

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I only have 1 LWC component, the date field is a standard flow screen component.

Comment: @ViqMontana That makes it a bit tricker and I do not think the answers I provided would work.
I am not sure you can have a LWC listening to a standard flow component but if you are able to set a record's field with the standard flow component you may be able to catch that field update in a LWC component.